# How to increase Google Cloud Sql instance storage size

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We are a google cloud sql paid customer.

We are having default 250 GB storage space instance, we want to increase it up to 500 GB (The maximum limit).

How to do it?

As of now we are in bronze support plan

Comment: bronze customers can't direct talk with their support team and mentioned us  to post here

Comment: ah, you learn something every day :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Cloud SQL storage increase, send a request to 'cloud-sql@google.com' including your instance name.  You will receive an auto-response, but the Google Cloud Support team does review and respond to all storage increase requests.

From: https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#storage_limits:

The size of all instances is limited to 250GB by default. Note that you only pay for the storage that you use, so you don’t need to reserve this storage in advance. The limits on storage are determined by the time it takes to restore an instance from backup in case of a problem, and we cannot guarantee to restore instances larger than 250GB within 24 hours (smaller instances restore a lot faster). If you require more storage, up to 500GB, then it is possible to increase limits for individual instances for customers with a Silver or higher Google Cloud support package.